# Утечка памяти в функции (Си)

Tags: c, указатели, память, float

Функция предназначена для формирования из строки массива вещественных чисел (все данные программа получает в виде текстового файла, из которого должна составить массив структур) с помощью указателей на части строки.
После дебага с помощью консоли обнаружилась проблема с памятью. Во-первых, после конца строки (переменная current_star) в ней содержался еще какой-то мусор, а во-вторых происходило переполнение памяти.
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарю!

```
float *arrayCreate(char *str_data, float *bstars, int *k)
{
    char *current_star = NULL, *cur_star_end; //current star size as a string
    int i = 0, sum = 0;

    bstars = NULL;
    cur_star_end = str_data;

    while (cur_star_end!=NULL)
    {
        cur_star_end = strchr(str_data, ' ');

        if (cur_star_end!=NULL)
        {
            current_star = (char*)realloc(current_star, sizeof(char)*(cur_star_end-str_data+1));
            strncpy(current_star, str_data, cur_star_end-str_data);
        }
        else
        {
            current_star = (char*)realloc(current_star, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(current_star, str_data);
        }

        if (strlen(current_star)!=1)
        {
            bstars = (float*)realloc(bstars, sizeof(float)*(i+1));
            bstars[i] = atof(current_star);
            sum += bstars[i];

            i++;

            if (cur_star_end!=NULL)
                str_data = cur_star_end+1;
        }
    }

    *k = i;

    free(current_star);
    current_star = NULL;
    free(str_data);
    str_data = NULL;

    return bstars;
}
```

Comment: `char *current_star = malloc(1);` это для начала.. `    bstars ` также...  Не плохо результаты алоков проверять, мало ли..

Comment: @NewView, а почему так? Мы получается при realloc'е добавим лишнюю ячейку памяти, да и к тому же, исходная строка может быть пустой

Comment: Не может она быть пустой, сперва надо выделить память, хоть один байт, а потом изменять его размер. И строка и выделенная память не есть одно и тоже.

Comment: @NewView: Ни в ком случае! Функция `realloc` прекрасно умеет работать с null-указателем на входе. Она эквивалента `malloc` в этом случае. Использование null на старте - это элегантнейший и хорошо установившийся паттерн использования `realloc`. Не надо превращать его в ужасное и никому не нужное `malloc(1)`.

Comment: ТС, можете мне дать весь код, для проверки?

Comment: @misdeed Он очень сырой, поэтому не знаю, возьметесь ли вы за такое

Comment: @AnT, практически с нулемым указателем realloc становиться malloc'ом :) но так делать не стоит из эстетических соображений, и читаемость кода. И понимания того что делаем ресайз, размывается при таком подходе, и потом при поиске например в исходниках, это создаёт определённые неудобства. ИМХО конечно :)

Comment: Автор, а чем вы это собираете? В плане компилятора и платформы.

Comment: @NewView: Нет, именно так и стоит делать - это естественная и общепринятая договоренность, дающая компактный, аккуратный, элегантный и чистый код. Не вижу никаких проблем с "пониманием того что делаем ресайз" в этом случае. А вот `malloc(1)` там, где он не нужен вообще - признак очень замусоренного и некачественного кода.

Comment: @NewView CodeBlocks 16.1 Компилятор - GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: У GCC есть великолепные инструменты по работе с выделенной памятью под переменные, попробуйте использовать их вместо `free`: `char *current_star = __attribute__ ((__cleanup__(clean_up))) = NULL;` при этом не надо следить за точкой выхода из функции, переменная всегда будет очищена. `void clan_up(void**);` - это функция очищающая выделенный элемент. Попробуйте, и утечки памяти сведуться к нулю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Очевидная и часто возникающая ошибка

   ```
   current_star = (char*)realloc(current_star, sizeof(char)*(cur_star_end-str_data+1));
   strncpy(current_star, str_data, cur_star_end-str_data);
   ```

   за которым далее сразу следует

   ```
   if (strlen(current_star)!=1)
   ```

   Функция `strncpy` не предназначена для безопасного копирования строк и в общем случае не завершает буфер-получатель символом `'\0'`. Поведение вашей программы будет зависеть от того, что за мусор содержится в последнем байте, выделенном вашим `realloc`.

   Если вам все-таки приспичило использовать `strncpy` в этой роли, то не забывайте ставить `'\0'` в конце строки-получателя самостоятельно. Но, еще раз функция `strncpy` не предназначена для безопасного копирования строк и в современном коде практических применений почти не имеет.

   ```
   size_t length = cur_star_end - str_data;
   current_star = realloc(current_star, (length + 1) * sizeof *current_star);
   memcpy(current_star, str_data, length);
   current_star[length] = '\0';
   ```
2. Тут на самом деле возникает вопрос о том, зачем вы вообще пытаетесь "выкопировать" очередную подстроку из входных данных в отдельную строку `current_star`. Зачем, если перевод в число можно делать прямо там, в самих входных данных??? И никаких `realloc`-ов не понадобится.
3. Еще одна ошибка

   ```
   current_star = (char*)realloc(current_star, sizeof(char));
   strcpy(current_star, str_data);
   ```

   Что это? С чего вы решили, что "хвост" строки `str_data` поместится в один-единственный `char`?

   ```
   size_t length = strlen(str_data);
   current_star = realloc(current_star, (length + 1) * sizeof *current_star);
   strcpy(current_star, str_data);
   ```
4. Что означает проверка

   ```
   if (strlen(current_star)!=1)
   ```

   У вас что, на вход не может прийти просто подстрока `3`?
5. Код не рассчитан на множественные пробелы между числами во входе. Это разрешено?
6. Функции группы `ato...` не предназначены для практического использования. Они существуют только для совместимости со старым кодом. Перевод строки в число в стандартной библиотеке С делается функциями группы `strto...`.
7. Явное приведение типа к `(char *)` на результате функции выделения пямяти - режет глаз.

Comment: "if (strlen(current_star)!=1)
У вас что, на вход не может прийти просто число 3?" - имелось в виду последний элемент массива, я уже не помню точно.

Comment: "Явное приведение типа к (char *) на результате функции выделения пямяти - режет глаз" - ну, это вроде бы как правильно. По крайней мере, нас так заставляют делать

Comment: @Xiamera: Эта проверка у вас делается для *всех* элементов входной строки, а не только для последнего.

Comment: @Xiamera: За такое "заставляние" надо отправлять преподавателей в армию или на сельхозработы.

Comment: Замечу, что опасно присваивать результат `realloc` тому же указателю, что используется в функции. При неудаче вернется `NULL` и будет утечка.

Comment: 5 пункт - единичный пробел в условии, но, действительно, наверное, стоит делать обход всей строки для "защиты от дурака"